# Stack frame for signal handling in the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals, linux-device-driver

I see that the stack frame the process needs to handle signals is allocated in the function `setup_rt_frame()`.

My question is: where it is de-allocated?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`setup_rt_frame()` sets stack for **Real-time signals** (see [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)). It does 2 main things:

1. Saves CPU context of user process (before it was interrupted) from kernel stack to user stack. 
    
   For ARM architecture it's done in [setup_sigframe()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/signal.c#L252).
2. Saves return address (where signal handler returns) to user stack. 
    
   Return address will point to `rt_sigreturn()` syscall (see [man 2 sigreturn](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigreturn.2.html) for details).  
   For ARM architecture it's done in [setup_return()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/signal.c#L252).

As you can see, once signal handler is finished, it will automatically return to [sys_rt_sigreturn()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/signal.c#L219) function in kernel. This function will restore kernel stack from user stack and get back to interrupted user-space process.

So, answering your question:

> where it is de-allocated?

It's being restored in `sys_rt_sigreturn()` function.

See also:

[1] [How signals work internally?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/how-signals-work-internally)

[2] [Who uses POSIX realtime signals and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345973/who-uses-posix-realtime-signals-and-why)

[3] [Implementation of signal handling](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~donnie/cs124/CS124Lec17.pdf) (see sections "Delivering Signals (7)" to "Delivering Signals (12)")